# In JavaScript, where do the constant strings returned from typeof come from?

Tags: javascript

I've seen a lot of places that do a string comparison with the *typeof* keyword and it returns what are obviously constant strings, such as *string*, *object*, *undefined* etc.  I would expect to see those defined as constants somewhere but it doesn't seem to be the case (they are listed on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)).  I don't like to see duplication of strings being used in code as they seem magic.  The current solution is to define them as *const* elsewhere in code myself but it seems JS knows these anyway so why can't I get to them? (or can I?)

magic string:

```
if(typeof myObject === 'object') {}
```

This seems a little better, since no duplication of magic string, but I don't see why I should have to define the const:

```
const TYPE_OBJECT = 'object';

if(typeof myObject === TYPE_OBJECT) {}  
if(typeof myOtherObject === TYPE_OBJECT) {}
```

Or, this seems clumsy too:

```
if(typeof myObject === Object.name.toLowerCase()) {}  
if(typeof "hello" === String.name.toLowerCase()) {}
```

Is there a better way or are these constants built in somewhere?

Comment: [ECMAScript 2015 - 12.5.6 The `typeof` Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typeof-operator)

Comment: What you're doing seems like the most legit way to go if you ask me.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for posting a link to the spec as it shows the constant strings being returned as in the MDN docs but I was asking if those constants are accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These string constants are not available as predefined constants. But if you don't want to specify those string literals yourself, you can do the inverse, and apply `typeof` to some basic values you provide, and define the constants with those returned strings. For instance:

```js
const TYPES = Object.freeze({
    OBJECT: typeof {},
    UNDEFINED: typeof undefined,
    BOOLEAN: typeof true,
    NUMBER: typeof 1,
    STRING: typeof "",
    FUNCTION: typeof eval,
    SYMBOL: typeof Symbol()
});

console.log(TYPES);

// Use it:
let myObject = { "test": 123 };
console.log(typeof myObject === TYPES.OBJECT); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the presumption that these strings have to *come from* somewhere is a fallacy. JavaScript is a spec and, in this regard, all there is to it that `typeof` is an operator that returns a string which can have one of the predefined values listed in the spec. Where these come from is thus implementation-dependent.

Furthermore, while things like `typeof myObject === Object.name.toLowerCase()` or `typeof myObject === TYPE_OBJECT` may seem better than using a "bare" string, `typeof myObject === 'object'` is a well-known pattern. By using something different, you are reducing the readability of your code, as the other two variants are guaranteed to raise some brows and prompt people to ask themselves what this line does.

Had `Symbol` existed in JS from the very start, I believe `typeof` would've just returned a `Symbol`. Sadly, for backwards-compatibility, it has to return a string.